# Sliding in the android app home screen

Tags: android

I am looking to create an app where some categories that the user can choose from will be shown. The best UI I could find is shown in this image:
https://lh3.ggpht.com/swzmwICOMNjKmLH_HyAWh0VQ49BN7vU6PG3qEpsSnF1HWcG1CmpQi1BTBxdVczZx8pY

The screenshot is of the "Parenting Ages & Stages" android app. The best part of the above shown home page is that there is no scroll bar at the bottom and the user can use swipe gestures to see various categories.

Any idea how I can achieve the same effect?

Comment: i think you can use ViewPager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: thanks, can you please post this as answer and I shall accept the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use ViewPager in your case

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

It may Help you!